# Any ideas for multiple (a lot of) modbus server connections with python

Tags: python, asynchronous, modbus

I'd say I'm more of a web fullstack developer, I don't know that much about python, but I need to create a program that connects to many modbus servers at the same time. Currently, a SCADA program does this job, but it has a lot of drawbacks and is not very customizable, and would also need a web representation.

The main problem is that there are many modbus servers that need to read values for 1-2 registers per second, and then, counting these values, would need to write data to another register.
These servers are separate islands in some cities, but with internet access. There are about 20-30 of these islands, each with its own network address, and within these islands there are 1-40 Modbus servers, each communicating on a separate fixed port.

The main reason for a custom software solution is that I usually have to redesign the interface, the control, the calculations. This is a bit problematic when you have hundreds of endpoints or objects to reprogram, so I would need a solution where I edit a parent object once and its properties are inherited by the other objects. And unfortunately this needs to run on linux VPS

Can anyone recommend a good python modbus module that can solve the above problem with relatively low response time?
A special advantage would be to be able to measure the response time or the quality of the connection to check if the desired value has reached the server.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Choosing a different SCADA platform for the modbus data display (Ignition has a Web UI and can connect to many modbus devices) would probably be your best choice. Implementing something robust and useful would probably take many months.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, so I'm wondering if Ignition can generate modbus objects from a database based on given parameters?
The main reason for a custom software solution is that I usually have to redesign the interface, the control, the calculations. This is a bit problematic when you have hundreds of endpoints to reprogram, so I would need a solution where I edit an object once and its properties are inherited by the other objects. And unfortunately this needs to run on linux VPS

Comment: https://docs.inductiveautomation.com/display/DOC81/Modbus+Address+Mapping This sounds like what you want. It lets you map registers in the modbus device to opc items, and then those items can be mapped into tags and displayed on the Ignition web HMI